# Получить ключи из объекта массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, frontend

Всем привет.

Имеется массив с объектами. Задача: Получить ключи значений из объекта.
Пытаюсь решить через Object.key, получаю ключи самих объектов.

Вот код:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
       console.log(key);
       }
```

Comment: "Задача: Получить ключи" ---- "через Object.key, получаю ключи "........ в чём проблема тогда?

Comment: Допиши в вопрос пример данных и то, что хочешь получить из этого

Comment: полагаю data.forEach( el => console.log(Object.keys(el)) )

Answer (score 0):

По заданию есть массив объектов:

```
let array = [{a: 1}, {b: 1}, {c : 3}];
```

Нам необходимо получить ключи объектов в массиве, для этого используем функцию массива - reduce:

```
let keys = array.reduce((container, obj) => [...container, ...Object.keys(obj)], []);
```

Тем самым получаем все ключи, присутствующие в каждом объекте из массива.
Так же можем получить уникальные ключи (массив ключей без дубликатов), используя Set:

```
let uniqueKeys = [...new Set(keys)];
```

Comment: вместо reduce, тут удобнее [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 0):

Вы получаете ключи самих объектов потому что перебираете ключи массива, а нужно перебирать ключи самих элементов массива, для этого можно пройтись по ним с помощью цикла (for..of)

```js
let data = [{
  o1k1: 1,
  o1k2: 2
}, {
  o2k1: 1,
  o2k2: 2
}];

for (obj of data) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key);
  })
  console.log("---");
}
```